# googlemaps.exceptions.HTTPError: HTTP Error: 400

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, google-maps, reverse-geocoding

I have this block of code in python

```
from googlemaps import Client
apiKey = 'xxxx'
lat = input("Please enter latitude: ")
lng = input("Please enter longitude: ")
maps = Client(apiKey)
reverseGeo = maps.reverse_geocode(lat,lng)
address = reverseGeo['Placemark'][0]['address']
print(address)
```

Whenever i try to run and input the lat and lng value, this error happens:

```
Please enter latitude: 5
Please enter longitude: 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Programs/github/mobile_application_development/Ex 1/part 1/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    reverseGeo = maps.reverse_geocode(lat,lng)
  File "C:\Users\Truong Dang\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python34\site-packages\googlemaps\client.py", line 356, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Truong Dang\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python34\site-packages\googlemaps\geocoding.py", line 109, in reverse_geocode
    return client._request("/maps/api/geocode/json", params)["results"]
  File "C:\Users\Truong Dang\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python34\site-packages\googlemaps\client.py", line 253, in _request
    result = self._get_body(response)
  File "C:\Users\Truong Dang\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python34\site-packages\googlemaps\client.py", line 267, in _get_body
    raise googlemaps.exceptions.HTTPError(response.status_code)
googlemaps.exceptions.HTTPError: HTTP Error: 400
```

Can I ask for a reason and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code I think you need to pass the Latidude longitude as a single argument in one of these forms:

1. A list `maps.reverse_geocode([lat, lng])`
2. A comma seperated string: `maps.reverse_geocode(lat + ',' + lng)`
3. A tuple `maps.reverse_geocode((lat, lng))`

Basically the first argument to reverse_geocode is given to [normalize_lat_lng](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python/blob/master/googlemaps/convert.py) where you can see what representations are supported

Comment: Thank you, that's definitely the problem!